# Connecting to MariaDB in C# Application using raspbian

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I've been trying to run a server on my pi3 that uses mysql (mariadb) and connects like this:

```
mySQLSettings.connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=servertest;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");
mySQLSettings.connection.Open();
```

It works perfectly fine on Windows when i use XAMPP. However when i run the app on my pi it throws me this:

```
Could not connect to MySQL: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket () [0x0006e] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateNew (System.Boolean reset) [0x000ed] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate (System.Boolean reset) [0x00040] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00344] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000c] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x00058] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () [0x0001e] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x000b5] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x00051] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () [0x00021] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0013e] in <61bbf0b98df94765b3636dc3aa92c9d7>:0
  at GameServer.MySQL.ConnectToMySQLServer () [0x00000] in <16fb46a8a2244c9e90373e583102cae7>:0
```

The version of MariaDB is 10.3.22 and I'm using the MySql.Data-6.4 dll

Am I missing something simple?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a pretty old version of MySql.Data.dll, which may not support the authentication scheme your server is using.

In this case, I'd recommend switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which has better client support for MariaDB, including its `auth_gss_client` and `auth_ed25519` authentication schemes (the latter in a [separate package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector.Authentication.Ed25519/)).

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! That seems like the issue. However I don't find how i can install the mysqlconnector. Can you explain me how i can do that? I'm pretty new to work in a terminal

Comment: If you're using a terminal, and .NET Core: `dotnet add package MySqlConnector`. You may need to edit the CSPROJ file to remove `MySql.Data`.

Comment: I added the MySqlConnector, and removed the MySql.Data in the .csproj. However when i try to compile it with ```mcs -out:build/server.exe *.cs``` i get this error: ```error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MySql' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?```. On my first version i managed to to compile it with ```-r:MySql.Data.dll``` But since i'm not using the old dll anymore i don't have the file. So how can I give the compiler the assembly reference?

Comment: I don't use `mcs` but I imagine you'd have to reference MySqlConnector with `-r:MySqlConnector.dll`. If you have to manually pick a particular DLL then probably the `netstandard2.0` one is likely to work well.

Comment: I'd need the absolute path for that, how can I see where it got installed the MySqlConnector.dll

Also if you think there is an easier way than using mcs, i can try to change that

Comment: I'd probably personally try to use .NET Core; in my experience it's as simple as `dotnet add package` and `dotnet build`. This guy installed the SDK on a Pi: https://edi.wang/post/2019/9/29/setup-net-core-30-runtime-and-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-4. These are instructions for building on a different platform and copying to a Pi: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

Comment: Turns out ```dotnet build``` works perfectly fine, I can compile it and start it. Only get an Error for access denied. But I will be able to take care of that myself. Thank you very much!